# Is there any significance to the license plates of the Winchester's Chevy Impala?

Tags: supernatural

In the first two seasons the license plate `KAZ 2Y5` is a Kansas plate denoting the show's first year, 2005. Later on it changes to `CNK 80Q3` when they are hiding from the FBI. Is there any significance to this license plate? CNK is apparently an Ohio plate, but besides that 80Q3 is a mystery to me. Also, are there any other plates they use for an extended period of time?

Comment: You have a scary attention to details

Comment: Oh come on, nearly every episode there's a close up of the back of car. How can you not notice?

Comment: I probably did read them and even notice the meaning of `KAZ 2Y5` at some point, but it's just not very important to the plot - I don't think I ever registered that it actually changed...

Comment: I haven't found it yet, but I wouldn't be surprised to discover that the plates give some reference to the series' creators or writers.  They do a lot of that in Supernatural.  For example, on another car in one episode, I once noticed a license plate that read `THE KRIP` - obviously a reference to creator Eric Kripke, if not actually a car that he owned.

Comment: In Fallen, the movie with Denzel Washington, Denzel's car also has the license plate starting with KAZ, interestingly enough the Demon in Fallen is Azazel....

Answer (score 7):

Expanding just a little bit on my comment:

People, places, and things in the Supernatural universe are often named for the series' creators, producers, writers, and/or other cast members.  Bobby Singer, named for Executive Producer Robert Singer, is one prominent example.  While I have not found anything to authoritatively state this is the case for the license plates, that's probably a good direction to look.

You may also be interested to know that `KAZ 2Y5` (Kansas) and `CNK 80Q3` (Ohio) aren't the only plates to have been on the Impala.  According to the [Super-Wiki](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Impala), these are the plates the Impala has had to date:

- `C-45P4` (1973)
- `BQN 9R3` (1997)
- `KAZ 2Y5` (2005-07)
- `RMD 5H2` (Alternate reality in *Wish Verse*, 2006)
- `CNK 80Q3` (2007-Present)

The [Supernatural Wikia page](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/The_Impala) suggests that `KAZ` might be a reference to the brothers' home state of Kansas.  This does not appear supported by any canonical citation, however.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can think of an explanation for the first plate in the series, KAZ 2Y5, though the others are a mystery to me. Although the K could just be Kansas, it is also the first letter of the creator's, Eric Kripke's, last name. The 2Y5, well, the Y could be year, 2 - - 5, the show began in 2005. But this is all very much conjecture on my part, it is just something that I had noticed and pondered as well. :)

Comment: I more or less state this in my question...do you have anything more to add?

Answer (score 0):

The origins of Castiel
“Cassiel (Hebrew, Qafsiel Kaziel) is the Latin name of an archangel in post-biblical Judeo-Christian religion, particularly that of the Kabbalah.

Unlike many other angels, Cassiel is known for simply watching the events of the cosmos unfold with little interference. He is the angel of solitude and tears, and is said to preside over the death of kings.”

Yeah who does that sound like?

Also, his nickname is spelt Cass, although Castiel only has one s. The actual angel’s name has two s’.

Now look at the Hebrew name: KAZIEL

And what’s the Impala’s license plate read?

I feel smart now

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, 2Y5 could bye. B is the second letter in the alphabet and E is the fifth. So maybe it could mean Bye Kansas or something.

When I first thought at that, I litteraly couldn't stop checking if it still matched :p

Answer (score 0):

Here's my theory:
Best as I can see it the Kansas license plate KAZ 2Y5 refers to Kansas, the group that performs "Carry on Wayward Son". 2&5 could refer to the highest places the album Leftoverture, featuring "Carry on Wayward Son", reached on the music charts. It reached #2 in Canada and #5 in America. Y is and.

Answer (score -1):

I read some where that the KAZ 2Y5 is in fact a tribute to Kansas the boys home state, and the 2Y5 is the year 2005 when the show started. I'm fairly sure it was official site I found this one but I can't remember which.

Comment: The question already states that (first sentence).  You've added nothing new.  There's already an answer like this and it got the same type of comment from the QP. The question is asking about the CNK 80Q3 plate.

Comment: I'm going to downvote for lack of research, see @Stan's comment.